# Multiple regression lines to define a set of data

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to use a regression model to establish a relationship between two parameters, A and B(more specifically, runtime and workload, so that can I recommend what an optimal workload could be maybe, or how strongly one affects the other etc. ) I am using 'rlm'(robust linear model) for this purpose since it saves me the trouble of dealing with outliers before hand.

However, rather than output one single regression model, I would like to determine a band that can confidently explain most of the points. Here is an image I took from the web. Those additional red lines are what I want to determine.

[image]

This is what I had in mind : 
1. I found the mean of the residuals of all the points lying above the line. Then we probably shift the original regression line by some multiple of mean + k*sigma. The same can be done for the points below the line.

2. In SVM, in order to find the support vectors, we draw parallel lines(essentially shift the middle line until we find support vectors on either sides). I had something like that in mind. Play around with the intercepts a little and find the the number of points which can be explained by the band. Keep a threshold so you can stop somewhere.

The problem is, I am unable to implement this in R. For that matter, I am not sure if these approaches even work either. I would like to know what you would suggest. Also, is there a classic way to do this using one of the many R packages?

Thanks a lot for helping. Appreciate it.

Comment: Relevant reading maybe - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58446/ways-to-find-a-confidence-interval-for-robust-and-quantile-regressions